# Eclipse c++ build error. Permission deinied

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

After a war against Eclipse and MinGW, I managed to build a hello world program in Eclipse but now I am getting an annoying error. Sometimes when I try to build something I get:

```
cannot open output file *.exe: Permission denied
```

I have seen some answers around about this issue but none solved the problem. So here is some aditional info.

1) Usually, the first build works.

2) There is no process stuck in the task manager (as some suggessted).

3) I am using Windows 8 and MinGw.

4) No binary folder nor executable is created.

5) This problem happens chronologically.

Comment: Over aggressive or slow anti-virus can do this, but I don't know enough about your configuration to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: I have no anti-virus. What info/config should I gather to help diagnose?

Comment: If you literally get `*.exe`, best thing to find out is why it is using a wildcard for a file name. What happens if you build after a clean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed from MinGW to Cygwin and it worked.